# In FirstVC press button it parse value secondVC their append value in array display table view but when repeat process display new value replace new

Tags: swift4

// First View Button:

```
@objc func addToCartPressed(){

    let cartDestination = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addToCart") as! addToCartViewController
    cartDestination.title = "Cart"
    cartDestination.subMenuName = subMenuName
    cartDestination.subMenuPrice = sumTotal
    navigationController?.pushViewController(cartDestination, animated: true)

}
```

// Second view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    cartTableView.delegate = self
    cartTableView.dataSource = self

    subMenuNameArray.append(subMenuName)
    subMenuPriceArray.append(subMenuPrice)
}
```

TableView where i'm displaying by data when i clicked button in first view controller:

[image: TableView where i'm displaying by data when i clicked button in firstview controller]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = cartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = subMenuNameArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

First View Press Add to Cart it parse value to other VC and append value in array in 2nd VC and display in TableView when I repeat this process it overwrites its value:

[image: First View Press Add to Cart it parse value to other VC and append value in array in 2nd VC and display in TableView when I repeat this process it overwrites its value]

Answer (score 0):

You may have fallen into the reference vs value type trap.

These two lines may be copying the array instead of referencing it. Any changes in the second VC will only appear in the secondVC's data.

```
 cartDestination.subMenuName = subMenuName
 cartDestination.subMenuPrice = sumTotal
```

The simplest work around to this is to pass a reference of FirstVC to SecondVC and access its values. Any changes will then be reflected in the FirstVC

Example

FIRST VC

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController {
 // Code ...\
@objc func addToCartPressed(){

    let cartDestination = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addToCart") as! addToCartViewController
    cartDestination.title = "Cart"
    cartDestination.sourceVC = self // Here we pass the reference
    navigationController?.pushViewController(cartDestination, animated: true)
}
}
```

SecondVC

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController {

weak var sourceVC: FirstVC? // But make sure the reference is weak to avoid cycles

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    cartTableView.delegate = self
    cartTableView.dataSource = self

    self.sourceVC?.subMenuNameArray.append(subMenuName)
    self.sourceVC?.subMenuPriceArray.append(subMenuPrice)
}
```

With time you may prefer to use protocols instead of classes to reference the datasource, but this will work.

Read on value vs referencetypes [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9481-reference-vs-value-types-in-swift)